# Seting directory automatically in ArcGIS GUI Batch Commands?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, batch

When I do a batch command in ArcGIS e.g. Projection transformation the batch dialog has a field for the "new file name".

However, the default Directory is always the same folder as the original files.

If I want to change the Directory but keep the old names, then there is a strange syntax which I can use, something like `%n%`, but I would still have to copy and paste the complete path to the new folder.

Is there an option to simply pick a new folder and have the rest complete automatically?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to running tool in batch mode by right clicking it and choosing `Batch...` you can also write a small python script. There you can run your desired tool in a loop with your specific logic of providing output location. i.e. by setting output folder for shp or output GDB for featureclasses or even modifying featureclass name with some counter or whatever.

If you want "simply pick a new folder and viola" then for `Project (Data Management)` tool there are already prepared script in ArcToolbox: `Data Management Tools\Projections and Transformations\Feature\Batch Project`

You can right click it, choose `Edit...` and then use that Python script as an example for writing your own one for different tools.

Comment: ok Thanks.....Does anyone know this "syntax" well that I mentioned?...with the %n% variable?  Maybe there is a way to set a new directory with that...then I don´t have to bother with Python. The problem is that it is for other ArcGIS users who rarely do geoprocessing, so using python is a bit too applied!

Comment: You can prepare script for them and they can use it as a common tool. Like you can use `Data Management Tools\Projections and Transformations\Feature\Batch Project` and don't even know that it is python script inside.